# How to identify the position of string element stored in one column in a vector stored in another column of a tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, tibble

I have a tibble with two columns named ID and VEC.
ID stores a specific string, whereas VEC stores a vector including the string that is stored in column ID.

I would like to identify the position of the string in ID in the vector stored in VEC for each specific row.

Usually when just looking for a String in any vector I would go like this:

which(ID == VEC) - which would return the position.

However whenever trying to do this using mutate, R returns an error.

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:7, VEC = list(1:7, 1:7, 1:7, 1:7, 1:7, 
    1:7, 1:7)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

df %>%
  mutate(POS = which(ID == VEC))
```

I would like to add a new column with the position of the STRING in ID based on the vector that is stored in VEC.

Unfortunately I get this error massage:
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'.

Is there any way to do this using mutate?

Comment: I don't see any strings so not entirely sure what you need. Perhaps: `df %>% mutate(POS = purrr::map2_dbl(df$ID, df$VEC, ~ which(.x == .y)))`

Comment: awesome. that worked! and you're correct, my reproducible example used integers instead of strings in the ID column, the real tibble however uses strings. but anyways. the problem is solved now!